# Two folders are being created when i try to install HAXM

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-emulator, haxm

I updated Android Studio and my emulator stopped working. I have tried all the possible solutions .didn't work. I found that when I try to install intel HAXM via sdk manager, two folders are being created. and warning shows **"Package "com.android.repository.impl.generated.v1.RemotePackage@44b0bc2c" (extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager) should be installed in
"/Users/myPc/Library/Android/sdk/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager" but
it already exists.
Installing in "/Users/myPc/Library/Android/sdk/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager-2" instead."**
what should I do?

Comment: Did you discover what the issue was for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a folder Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager in /Users/myPc/Library/Android/sdk/extras/intel then i installed Haxm through Sdk manager, its worked form me

Answer (score 0):

It may sound trivial but check the following points in the release notes

Important:

1. Intel HAXM cannot be used on systems without an Intel processor, or an Intel processor lacking the hardware features, described in the "Hardware Requirements" section above.
   To determine the capabilities of your Intel processor, please visit http://ark.intel.com/

Comment: This does not answer the question. Same issue for me.

Comment: @BrillPappin I added an answer. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

**Hypothesis:** The HAXM installer is bumping against recent OS security measures (in my case, macOS Big Sur) and the useful part of the error information is buried by Android Studio.

**Workaround:**

1. Download the latest HAXM installer release from [Intel's GitHub repo](https://github.com/intel/haxm).
2. Unzip it.
3. In a terminal window, cd into the unzipped directory e.g. `cd ~/Downloads/haxm-macosx_v7_7_0/`
4. `chmod u+x silent_install.sh`
5. `sudo ./silent_install.sh`
6. Then macOS alerted that the extension needs extra permissions. It offered to open the Security & Privacy pane of System Preferences.
7. Unlock the pane then grant permission to the HAXM extension.
8. Consider looking through the log file `/tmp/haxm_silent_run.log` now since rebooting will delete it.
9. Reboot for the permission change to take effect.
10. Delete the installer `~/Downloads/haxm-macosx_v7_7_0/`.